# SQLite-net Query not returning rows

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin to create an Android app. I have a preexisting sqlite database that I am loading on to the device.

I am using the Sqlite-Net nuget package by Frank Kreuger.

In the db, I have a table names Lists that currently has one row in it.

I am using the Query method to try and retrieve the row. But it is not being returned.

I open the connection

```
db = new SQLiteConnection(FileAccessHelper.GetDBLocation(dbName));
```

Which give me a connection to my database located at
        DatabasePath    "/data/user/0/readdb.readdb/files/packinglists.sqlite"

I then try and retrieve the rows

```
try
{
    List<tabledefs.Lists> myLists = db.Query<tabledefs.Lists>("select * from Lists");
    foreach (tabledefs.Lists list in myLists)
    {
        listNames[counter++] = list.ListName;
    }
}catch (Exception e)
{
    //do something
}
```

The call does not return any rows even though I can open the DB manually and query the data.

Answer (score -2):

Haven't really fiddled with SQLite on a mobile device but pretty sure the process is the same as for a web service.

```
// Location of the Database
string connectionString;

// Use a "Using" instead of a try-catch-finally statement for automatic Dispose
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection (connectionString))
{
   // Use a Data Adapter and CommandBuilder to initiate and receive the data from the db.
   SQLiteDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter ("select * from Lists", connectionString);
   SQLiteCommandBuilder myCommand = new SQLiteCommandBuilder (myDataAdapter);

   // Create a Data Table to Store the db
   // Open the Database
   // Fill the Data Table from the Adapter that received the db
   DataTable newDataTable = new DataTable;
   db.Open();
   myDataAdapter.Fill (newDataTable);

   // Now if you run through each row and use "row.ItemArray[]" you can get 
   // the specific data type in each value.
   foreach (DataRow row in newDataTable.Rows)
   {
       "Your Rows Here"
   }
}
```

Should give you each row individually all you have to do is cast each index of the row to the correct value type to get the value of the column.